# AWS API limit: how to know programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I'm not wrong, current Amazon Advertising API limit can be calculated based upon these digits:

2,000 + 500 * [Average associate revenue driven per day over the past 30 days period]/24

Are there any ways to get an amount of remaining requests?

For example: 2605 has been made and 1300 can be done till the end of current hour for my account (or something like that).

Or should I just rely on 503 error message ("Account limit of 2000 requests per hour exceeded") ?